# "Wear like mirror surface is found in wide area where top, second, and oil ring slide"

Tags: translation

I was asked to translate something and the sentence was

> Wear like mirror surface is found in wide area where top, second, and oil ring slide

I translated it as:

> トップとセコンドとオイルリング所に広い摩耗の鏡面が見える

After I explained the English sentence to my Senpai, he then corrected it to be:

> 摩耗して鏡面のようになっている部分がトップとセコンドとオイルリングスライド所の広い
> 範囲である

I know hes right and used more natural Japanese than I did but I want to know your
opinion. Was my sentence hard to understand that it had to be corrected?

And what`s the difference between his and my sentence? Cause I still think my
sentence is more understandable (too me anyway). How do I change my way of thinking
so I can imitate his sentence structure more?

Comment: The English sentence looks kind of odd.

Comment: The sentence is about an engine? The word "slide" in the `top, second, and oil ring slide` is a verb, not a noun, right? In your Sempai's translation, it's translated as a noun　-> トップとセコンドとオイルリングスライドの所 (<- I think you're missing a の between スライド and 所)

Comment: Wear like mirror surface --> 鏡面のような  _________ in general, Yours is a bit too condensed.  Also, try to keep the original order of keywords, if possible.

Comment: chocolate-Yes its about a part of an  engine. Oil Ring slide is a noun.  Ah yes, I'll add that in. Thanks

Comment: H. Ha: But isn't Japanese  the total opposite of how English words are ordered most of the time?  How does のような translate here? "Like"?

Comment: The English is ungrammatical itself. If 'oil ring slide' is a noun, it should say say "Mirror-surface-like wear is found in wide areas such as the top, second, and oil ring slides". If it's a verb if it should be "... found where the top, second, and oil ring slide". It's difficult to translate when the original meaning isn't clear at all.

Comment: Heh.. If "Oil Ring slide" is a noun, then what's the verb of "top, second, and oil ring slide"?

Comment: Yeah, that's **_terrible_** English in the source text.  No wonder this was difficult to translate.  A minor fix might be: _"A̲ wear-̲like mirror surface is found in a̲ wide area where t̲h̲e̲ top, second, and oil ring slide."_  ← Underlines to indicate additions Grammatically, the word _"slide"_ must be a verb. The fixed version is still wonky, but it's less ambiguous and at least understandable.

Answer (score 5):

This sentence is about "ring wear grooves of cylinders" found in the middle of [this article](http://atvillustrated.com/content/engine-primer-4stroke-rebuild), right? I'm assuming "slide" at the end of the sentence is a **verb**. After some googling, I could not find a part called "a ring slide" in pistons.

And is this native speaker an engineer who is good at English? His translation does not seem natural; actually your translation attempt looks even better to me.

I would translate this as:

> - トップリング、セカンドリング、オイルリングがすべる広い範囲に鏡面のような摩耗が見える。
> - トップ・セカンド・オイルの各リングが[摺動【しゅうどう】する](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%91%BA%E5%8B%95)広範な部位に鏡面【きょうめん】状【じょう】の摩耗が認められる。

The second one should look more technical. Engines are beyond my scope of expertise, and real experts may further improve this.

- リング所 would mean nothing to me. Don't directly connect arbitrary nouns with 所. It simply does not work.
- ×セコンド　→　セカンド
- 摩耗の鏡面 makes little sense, but it would be taken as something like "worn mirror surface" as if you were talking about an actual mirror.
- As this is a technical sentence, I chose technical-sounding words (広い → 広範な, 見える → 認められる, すべる → 摺動する). I'm not really familiar with the word 摺動, but many Japanese articles about pistons (like [this](http://www.riken.co.jp/pistonring/piston/topring.html)) seem to use this term.
- 状 is another handy suffix which means "-like", "-oid", "in the form of ～". (e.g., 円盤状 = discoid, 棒状 = rod-like)
- In the first example I explicitly said 「トップリング、セカンドリング、オイルリング」 to avoid any confusion. You can also say 「トップ・セカンド・オイルリング」 or 「トップ・セカンド・オイルの3つのリング」.